# Manipulate text in es6

Tags: javascript

I have a few strings that I need to make sure they're existed before I can save them.
If a string is existed, I have to add a comma right after it. But if not, it shouldn't save the string and not the comma. Because it's not existed.
For example:

```
home, car, airplane,
```

In case of airplane, if it's existed it should be shown normally with a comma after it. But if it's not existed it should show helicopter instead, with a comma.

I tried this code but it seems like it's not working (I don't see any commas):

```
const data = `${object.home && object.home && ", "}${
              object.car && object.car && ", "
            }${object.airplane ? object.airplane && ", " : object.helicopter && ", " }`
```

What would be the right way to do that?

Comment: object is an object that comes from the API and it has to stay as an object and not an array because the strings have unique names and unique meanings (not just str1 and str2...) I just edited the question with unique names for the string. Let me know if it's more clear now.

Comment: Did you try using + instead of && to concatenate the comma?

Comment: First learn about the [operators](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Condition operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse

```
var object = { home:"home", car:"car", airplane:"airplane" }
const data = `${object.home ? object.home + ", ": ""}${object.car ? object.car + ", ": ""}${object.airplane ? object.airplane : ""}`
console.log(data) \\ home, car, airplane
```